# getAttribute() not working for class name?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a touchscreen project, and try to show a few images(split one line into a few paragraphs, and use background of each paragraph to display the image), and add border for selected image (only one could be selected), now I need to display shifted images by onclick(), for example, at first it shows image 1-6, after clicking, it should display images 2-7, the problem is my border belongs to each paragraph and does not move with images, I am trying to check whether the image is selected before I slide move the image.

I could set background image for paragraph with setattribute(), assume one paragraph has the id "img5", another paragraph has id "img6":
 `document.getElementById('img5').setAttribute("class", "noborder");
 document.getElementById('img6').setAttribute("class", "borderstyle1");`
then when I try to get the attribute:
`var x= document.getElementById('img1').getAttribute('class');
  if(x.equals("borderStyle1"))
  {.....}`
but the above is stuck and it reminds me : Uncaught TypeError: x.equals is not a function, any suggestions? thanks

Comment: `x.equals` ? What is the `equals` method, I've never heard of it (it's not a String method)

Answer (score 1):

Think you mean:

```
if (x === 'borderStyle1') {}
```

`x` value is a string after you call the `.getAttribute` method on the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to x == "borderStyle1" for comparing text string

```
if(x.equals("borderStyle1")){
}
```

to

```js
var x= document.getElementById('img1').getAttribute('class');
 if(x == "test1"){
 alert('ok');
 }
```

```html
<img src="" id="img1" class="test1" />
```